# How reference an object with foreign key on Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: database, oracle, object, plsql

I've created these two objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tp_endereco AS OBJECT (
    ID INTEGER, 
    DESCRICAO VARCHAR2(100), 
    CEP VARCHAR2(30) );

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tp_hospedagem AS OBJECT (
    ID INTEGER, 
    NOME VARCHAR2(200), 
    ENDERECO_FK_ID tp_endereco, 
    VALOR NUMBER(9,2), 
    TIPO_ACOMODACAO VARCHAR2(20) );
```

And then I've created a table of objects:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_endereco OF tp_endereco (PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

But, I dont know how to create the table of type TP_HOSPEDAGEM. How can I implement the FK ENDERECO_FK_ID constraint?

If I try this, I have an error:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_hospedagem OF tp_hospedagem (PRIMARY KEY (id) FOREIGN KEY (endereco_fk_id));
```

This happen because are different types, but I still lost.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you, guys!

Comment: Why do you want those types by the way? Why not simply create normal tables and refer to their ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why your doing in such way, maybe you are working on orcale forms however try the below(note that you have to change the name of the table):

```
CREATE TABLE tp_endereco_obj OF tp_endereco (ID PRIMARY KEY)
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY;
/
CREATE TABLE table_hospedagem OF tp_hospedagem (PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tp_endereco_obj (id));
/
```

Comment: Didn't work: 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: Hi man. It worked, thanks. But why we dont use endereco_fk_id as FK (FOREIGN KEY (endereco_fk_id))?

Comment: @LucasBacciotti beacaus endereco_fk_id is an object not a column, you have to reference a column with a column. I am really confused of what you are doing but i am fixing the error you had.

Comment: thanks man, It solved my issue. It is just a simple homework from my masters degree. My professor requested for that! Thanks again!